# for loop with input - PYTHON

Tags: python, list, for-loop, input

I have to program a pizza ordering system using python. In part of my program i have to ask how many pizzas the user would like and then they would choose from the list of pizzas what kind they would like, they would have to choose different pizzas. I want to use a for loop to repeat the input question as many times as the input where the user says how many pizzas they would like.

So far I have two parts of my code. My first input question:

```
pizza_number= int(input("How many Pizzas do you want? (MAX 5): "))
```

and the list of pizzas:

```
PIZZA_LIST=["Tandoori chicken: $8.50", "Prawn: $8.50", "Ham and cheese: $8.50", "Pepperoni: $8.50", "Hawaiian: $8.50","Beef and onion: $8.50","Meat lovers: $8.50", "Satay chicken: $13.50", "Apricot chicken: $13.50", "Supreme cheese:13.50", "Italian beef: $13.50", "Mediterraneo: $13.50"]
for index in range(0, len(PIZZA_LIST)):
    print(index, PIZZA_LIST[index])
```

the menu will be shown to the user and each pizza will have a number next to it and when they say what pizza they want, they will type in the number corresponding to the pizza (e.g. 1 = Prawn, 2= Ham and cheese etc.)

how would I program the for loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got most of the parts in there. This is how you would put them together.

```
pizza_number= int(input("How many Pizzas do you want? (MAX 5): "))
PIZZA_LIST=["Tandoori chicken: $8.50", "Prawn: $8.50", "Ham and cheese: $8.50", "Pepperoni: $8.50", "Hawaiian: $8.50","Beef and onion: $8.50","Meat lovers: $8.50", "Satay chicken: $13.50", "Apricot chicken: $13.50", "Supreme cheese:13.50", "Italian beef: $13.50", "Mediterraneo: $13.50"]
pizzas = []
for i in range(pizza_number):
    for index in range(0, len(PIZZA_LIST)):
        print(index, PIZZA_LIST[index])
    pizza = int(input("Select a pizza: "))
    pizzas.append(pizza)
```

Comment: Please check the edit. I've added exactly what you need to do.

Comment: Great, works perfectly thank you, but do you think you could explain briefly how it works, i understand a little bit but i don't feel like i am learning much by just copying in your code without understanding fully.

Comment: You're looping 'pizza_number' times and each time you are displaying the pizza list and asking the user to enter a choice. You store these choices in a list called 'pizza'.